# How to use Rest API as a source in dataflow in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF. I am creating a small demo where I am trying to hit a sample API "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees" and inserting data into the Employee table in the SQL database.

However, I would also like to add data flow to perform few select and other transformations on other related tables.
Below are the things that I have done so far in azure data factory:

1. Created a linked service called "EmployeeRestService" to communicate with the above api. 
   [image]
2. Created a linked service called "AzureSqlDatabase" to communicate with azure sql database
   [image]
3. Created a dataset "EmployeeApiDataset" of type "Rest" and linked it with "EmployeeRestService".
   [image]
4. Created a dataset of type Azure sql database and Selected "EmployeeTable".
5. Added one data flow (Now here I am getting the problem) 
   [image: data flow source settings] 
    
   [image: data flow source options]

And here is the error snapshot:
[image: Error]

In the data flow --> Source Settings, I selected "EmployeeApiDataset". But when I am trying to preview the data by enabling the debug, I am getting below error (refer above snapshot):
at Source 'EmployeeApi': Rest Sink - Error response received from the server (url:http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees,request body: None, request method: GET,  status code: 429), response body: Some(

Is this a correct way of doing adding Rest data source in data flow?
Note: I do not want to create an Azure data lake to store API results.

Can anybody suggest to me why I am getting the above error and what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `429 Too Many Requests` is an HTTP error code thrown by the target server, not anything in your workflow. If you open the URL in your browser, you'll see that the target site is returning this status code.

Comment: Interesting.. !!! But am I going in the right direction. Is it possible to use Rest Api as a source in my data flow this way?

Comment: This should work. Can you try it as an inline dataset type in your source instead?

Answer (score 1):

As @esqew mentioned in the comments, there is nothing wrong with your dataflow Source settings. As you are using **online dummy Rest API** as your source dataset, there are high chances that too many requests are made to call the Rest API by users.

1. I also got the same error when tried.

[image]

2. Also got the same 429 error when tested the URL.

[image]

3. I just hit the refresh and got the data in the source data preview.

[image]